# How to make the result of "print df" equal the result of "df"

Tags: dataframe, printing

[image: Code sample]

Like the picture above, the df is dataframe, I want the result of running `print df` on jupyter is dataframe. If `tpye(print df)`,the answer is `NoneType` instead `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: click the "enter image description here",you will see the picture

Answer (score 0):

Now,I figure it out later.Acctually,my boss told me the answer.thanks to my boss.it is akward to answer my own question,but I still want to answer it in case someone else id in the same situation as me.And everybody can discuss the answer,I think there is better answer.
It can use **display**

**from IPython.display import display,HTML**

**display(df)**

so I can see df in a def.